# How to register with a notification web service?

Tags: java, web-services, notifications

I had a bit of experience with JAX-WS to build some basic web services such as providing methods for clients to call.

But what if I have a notification service and clients will be able to register to the service to receive notification messages once there are some new updates?

Are there any guidelines for such web services?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [messaging specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications#Messaging_Specification) for some ideas.

WS-Eventing seems to fall close to your requirements, WS-Notification as well. Don't know how is the support for these two specs in different frameworks, but WS-Addressing is supported by most implementations and you could built on top of it as a fallback, assuming if you don't need something very fancy.